# Dúvida sobre .NET Framework 3.5 e ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, visual-studio-2015

Eu preciso criar uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC utilizando o .NET Framework 3.5 seguintes passos:

File -> New -> Project, então escolho, Template Visual C# -> Web

depois `.NET Framework 3.5` e `APS.NET Empty Web Application`, ao clicar no botão "OK" deveria aparecer a janela de Selecionar o `Template MVC`, mas não aparece.

*Segue a imagem da janela que deveria aparecer.*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se alguém puder me ajudar.

Comment: A sua duvida não entendi, porque, são esses os passos para criar um projeto MVC é só finalizar clicando no OK. Depois que clica no Ok o que aparece?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De Acordo com a Própria Microsoft ela está sendo reformulada para a nova plataforma a .NET CORE, de qualquer forma hoje no .NET FRAMEWORK 3.5 Você não consegue fazer mais isso, apenas da versão 4.5 do Net Framework para frente, Seguem umas imagens para lhe ajudar.

[image: Aqui basta Selecionar WEB, Framework 4.5 e verá na direita a descrição onde Contém o Modelo MVC, Clicando em OK veja a Foto 2]

[image: Aqui você poderá escolher o Modo de desenvolvimento MVC, OBS Estou no Enterprise 2015 Patch 3]

Aqui basta Selecionar WEB, Framework 4.5 e verá na direita a descrição onde Contém o Modelo MVC, Clicando em OK veja a Foto 2
Espero ter ajudado, abraços.

Comment: Ah entendi, ajudou sim. Muito obrigada!